# If PageCount ist reached, start from First Page ( ASP Classic )

Tags: asp-classic

I have an Active Server Page, which displays Booking of the current Day. I setted the PageSize to two, so my display is displaying just 2 bookings per side, if there are more Records. So actually i have 8 bookings in my Recordset, so my ASP creates 4 Pages.

I wrote the following function:

```
Function getNext10(num)


getNext10 = CurrPage + 1


End Function
```

Finally i call that function in a meta tag, to automatically change the pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=paging.asp?PageNo=<% Response.Write(getNext10(CurrPage))%>" />
```

It is working like charm. 
But i have just one more Problem. If i do that like this the PageNo is increment endless.
My PageCount is 4.

So what i need in my function is a logic which checks whether the PageCount has been reached or not. If yes then he should start from the first page again, if not then increment until pagecount has reached.

Can someone help me with that? Thanks!!

EDIT:

I Wrote that function:

```
Function getNext10(num)


 getNext10 = num

 if getNext10 < i then  // In `i`, i have my pagecount (4), which i got from Recordset.PageCount
                        // I checked it with Response.Write()
 getNext10 = CurrPage + 1


 End if

 End Function
```

If i use `i` the if clause is not working, i dont know why. Its only working if i use directly a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the page number will always be 4, then you can make a check for that.

```
Function getNext10(num)
   if (num < i) then
      CurrPage = num + 1
   else
      CurrPage = 1 'Reset the page count
   end if
   'Updating the variable used to call the page iterator
   getNext10 = CurrPage
End Function
```

If you do not always know the page number then you will need to calculate the number of pages somehow to check against.

Comment: The Page number is variable. It can be 4 or 5 or 6 and so on. If have done something like you. I i found something which is wired. Please check my Question again i will update it

Comment: In your sample your are not resetting the value to 1.  You will be able to move pages up, but once the max is hit, you will not be able to go any further.  As you want to cycle back to the first page, add an else section which will return 1 and reset the value.  Also, have updated the code.